# how to read password protected xls file in golang

Tags: go, passwords, xls, protected

I have .xls file which is encrypted and I have the password for the same xls file I want to read that file using the password in golang and update in the database

Even how to do it using **shell script**  also be helpfull

Comment: You may use [Office Interop Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-primary-interop-assemblies) with the help of [`github.com/go-ole/go-ole`](https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole). Since what Microsoft® ships is supposed to be able to do _everything_ Office can do, I'd expect that API to be able to decrypt those documents. Of course, this limits you to the Windows™ platform and those interop assemblies must be installed (they are freeware though).

Answer (score -1):

If reading the file is what you need, then I suggest you to save the copy of XLS file without the password. It can be exporting the XLS to CSV without password protection.

Comment: I am writing IMAP server in Golang for reading mail and downloading xls attachment so the downloaded xls file is password protected and I know the password but hoe to unlock it and then read the file and do the operation programmatically